Ubuntu 24.04.4 LTS - since last update my HP laptop hangs after a couple of seconds
I want to report an issue on my HP EliteBook 8440p laptop. It started with the latest OS update (20/08/2024), which included i.a. a new kernel (6.8.0.40) and new intel-microcode (3.20240514). Since then it hangs at login screen or a couple of seconds after login in. Keyboard and mouse become unresponsive and the screen remain frozen.
This laptop always ran linux flawlessly until then. It is running on an intel core i5 VPro CPU.
I can boot and use it normally by selecting the previous kernel (6.5.0.45) with grub.
Any idea on how to overcome this problem?
Many thanks in advance.

I'd check your details; as Ubuntu 24.04 LTS hasn't yet reached 24.04.1, with 24.04.4 a couple not expected for a long time (after 24.10's release). You'll probably find you're using 22.04 as that uses the 5.15 kernel if using the GA kernel stack, with HWE recently switching to the 6.8 kernel stack....


Assuming the software is the problem, you can lock your kernel version to the last one that works. With respect to software packages, also these can be downgraded to previous versions that worked and then be locked.
After a while, perhaps several months, you can update to the latest versions to check whether this issue with your hardware has been resolved. If not, lock again on the current versions.

Do not exclude the possibility of hardware problems, though. If the issue continues to exist with the software versions that previously worked, failing hardware may be the cause. For diagnosis, you can run "sudo dmesg -w" in a terminal and display that window always on top. Typically, before the system locks up, red error messages will be displayed by the kernel. These can (at least to technical people) give a hint of where it goes wrong.


